# How to add LinkedHashMap elements to a list and use groupBy method in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I want to post three different version of my codes, out of which one working but I cannot go with that approach.

Version1: not working

```
List<LinkedHashMap> listOfRecords 
LinkedHashMap a = [product: 'p1', cluster: 'c1', salesorg: 's1']
LinkedHashMap b = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c2', salesorg: 's2']
LinkedHashMap c = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c3', salesorg: 's2']

listOfRecords.add(a)
listOfRecords.add(b)
listOfRecords.add(c)

println("listOfRecords : "+listOfRecords)
println("listOfRecords groupby : "+listOfRecords.groupBy { it.cluster })
```

> Script failed on line: 6, with error: An error occurred while processing this page.

Version2 : working, but I don't want to assign LinkedHashMap to list during the declaration.

```
LinkedHashMap a = [product: 'p1', cluster: 'c1', salesorg: 's1']
LinkedHashMap b = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c2', salesorg: 's2']
LinkedHashMap c = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c3', salesorg: 's2']

List listOfRecords=[a]
//listOfRecords.add(a)
listOfRecords.add(b)
listOfRecords.add(c)

println("listOfRecords : "+listOfRecords)
println("listOfRecords groupby : "+listOfRecords.groupBy { it.cluster })
```

Version3: not working. Since it has a validation error, I tried with version1 and version2

```
//List<LinkedHashMap> listOfRecords 
LinkedHashMap a = [product: 'p1', cluster: 'c1', salesorg: 's1']
LinkedHashMap b = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c2', salesorg: 's2']
LinkedHashMap c = [product: 'p2', cluster: 'c3', salesorg: 's2']

List listOfRecords;
//List listOfRecords=[a]
listOfRecords.add(a)
listOfRecords.add(b)
listOfRecords.add(c)

println("listOfRecords : "+listOfRecords)
println("listOfRecords groupby : "+listOfRecords.groupBy { it.cluster })
```

> A validation error was received from the Planning server.
>   'Error:The Groovy script failed to compile with internal error: Compile Error:
>   [Static type checking] - No such property: cluster for class: java.lang.Object
>   @ line 13, column 60. Rule SalesPLN.SALESREP.linkedhashmap'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To fix the top code you need to instantiate the list before using it. Try List<LinkedHashMap> listOfRecords = []

That's why the second code works, because you instantiated it with the element a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your original script gives an Null Pointer Exception, because you never initialize  `listOfRecords` (E.g. this should fix it: `def listOfRecords = []`).  The code tries to `add` to `listOfRecords`, which triggers the NPE.  Your second example does initialize your var and therefor works.

Why you get such a useless error message is beyond me though.